# How do search replace and merge textfile in python?

Tags: python, text, array-merge

**I have text file like** 

**file1.txt**

```
a=id01
desc=sample1
attribute1

a=id02
desc=sample2
attribute1
attribute2

a=id05
desc=sample5

a=id03
desc=sample3

a=id04
desc=sample4
```

**file2.txt**

```
id01=sample text id01 
id05=sample text id05
id02=sample text id02 
id03=sample text id03
id04=sample text id04
```

**The number of rows is not the same. and sorted random.**
**I want the following result after Combine those two files:**

**output.txt**

```
a=id01;  id01=sample text id01 
desc=sample1
attribute1

a=id02; id02=sample text id02 
desc=sample2
attribute1
attribute2

a=id03; id03=sample text id03 
desc=sample3

a=id04; id04=sample text id04 
desc=sample4

a=id05; id05=sample text id05 
desc=sample5
```

Comment: are file_1 and file_2 in same order like id01, id02, id03 ... etc? or in file_1 it can be id01, id03, id02, and in file_2 id02, id01 like also possible?

Comment: yes. sort random 
file_1 it can be id01, id03, id02,  and in file_2 id02, id01

Comment: What is the rule for matching id043 with id04?

Answer (score 1):

Due to a change in specification, this has been re-written:

```
import re

F1 = 'file1.txt'
F2 = 'file2.txt'
O1 = 'output.txt'

D = {}

EXPR = re.compile('^(.*)=(.*)$')

with open(F1) as f1:
    lines = iter(f1.readlines())
    try:
        while True:
            k = next(lines).strip()
            D[k] = [next(lines).strip()]
            while (_s := next(lines).strip()):
                D[k].append(_s)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

with open(O1, 'w') as o1:
    with open(F2) as f2:
        for line in sorted(f2.readlines()):
            try:
                k = 'a=' + EXPR.match(line)[1]
                if k in D:
                    o1.write(f'{k};  {line}')
                    for a in D[k]:
                        o1.write(f'{a}\n')
                    o1.write('\n')
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Comment: In which case, my suggestion **will not work**. It's a pity you didn't specify your problem properly when you first posed the question